# Truclient IE VUsers get stuck at Init state

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, alm, truclient

I have developed a Truclient script using LoadRunner 12.02 and it works find both in Truclient IE script developer and my local controller. The problem occurs only when I try to run it in ALM - Performance Center 11.52. All Virtual Users get stuck at "Init" state and never proceed to "Running" state.

I try to download RawResults.zip and investigate what's the issue but it does not show any error as the total number of VUsers running were zero.

Can it be that it does not work because I developed it using LoadRunner 12.02 and I am trying to run it in ALM - Performance Center 11.52 ?  I have not had this issue for  Web - HTTP/HTML protocol.

I am not an expricenced performance tester and I would really appriciate it if you assist me to troubleshoot this issue. I thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, all of your versions should be matched.  You are generally forward compatible for a couple of versions, but rarely backward compatible because of changes in libraries and API calls

Comment: Many thanks James. we downgraded LoadRunner to version 11.52 be compatible with our version of ALM Performance Center and it resolved the issue. Cheers :)

Comment: Glad to read it.  Thank you for posting the update with the resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed by downgrading LoadRunner to version 11.52 to make it compatible with the version of ALM Performance Center installed on server.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely you are trying to use a add-in in the script such as Adobe. There is a bug (or undocumented feature according tot the help desk). When using an add in the length of the name of total path effects script execution in controller. You need to save the script with a short name and in the root directory of a HDD to over come the issue you have.

Comment: Hi Scott, Thanks for you comment. Issue is already resolved and I have just added the solution worked for us. Thanks again